# Examples for Markov generators with pure point spectrum

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm looking at symmetric diffusion Markov generators $L$ with pure point spectrum, i.e. infinitesimal generators of symmetric diffusion Markov semigroups, which are defined on $L^2(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure. In functional analytic terms, $L$ is a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mu)$ sending the constants to zero, whose discrete spectrum is contained in the interval $(-\infty,0]$.

When looking at $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu)$, where $\mu$ admits exponential moments, and one assumes that the eigenfunctions of $L$ are orthogonal polynomials, the only three generators that can arise are the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck, Laguerre and Beta generator with the Hermite, Laguerre and Jacobi polynomials as eigenfunctions and spectrum $-\mathbb{N}_0 = \{ -n \mid n \geq 0 \}$ (OU- and Laguerre) or $\{ -n^2 \mid n \geq 0 \}$ (Jacobi). This has been shown in "Classification of diffusion semigroups in R associated with orthogonal polynomials [French]" by O. Mazet, see [MathSciNet review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=MR&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=MR1478714&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq")

I'm looking for other examples of such generators (with or without explicit semigroup) and any other connected results which describe the structure of the spectrum. I'm also thankful for references where I might find such examples or results.

To clarify, I'm looking for a self adjoint linear operator $L$ on $L^2(E,\mu)$ where

1. $\mu$ is a probability measure on some separable measure space $E$
2. The spectrum of $L$ is discrete
3. $L1=0$
4. $-L$ is positive
5. $L$ is diffusive, i.e. for all smooth functions $\varphi$, one has that $$L \varphi(f) = \varphi'(f) Lf + \varphi''(f) \Gamma(f,f),$$ where $\Gamma(f,g) = \frac{1}{2} \left( L(fg) - f Lg - g Lf \right)$ is the carre du champ operator associated to $L$. This condition describes that $L$ generates a diffusion semigroup.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want but Grigorchuk and Zuk showed that the Markov operator for a simple random walk on the lamplighter group with appropriate generating set has pure point spectrum.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by saying that "the only three generators that can arise are the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck, Laguerre and Beta generator". If you consider the Laplacian as a (very) special case of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator, then I agree. In any case, $\Delta$ on $L^2(\Omega)$, $|\Omega|=1$, with Neumann boundary conditions seems to be what you need: It generates a Markov semigroup under very mild regularity assumption on $\partial\Omega$ and its spectrum can be almost arbitrarily complicated, the main constraint being the (dimension dependent) Weyl asyptotic formula.

Comment: How does $L$ act on non-constant functions? Or is an abstract definition of $L$ contained in what you wrote?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo I've clarified my question and added a reference. Could you please give me a hint where I can find the results you quoted? I'm not an expert in Markov semigroups and not very familiar with the literature. Thank you very much!